# Save attachments of incoming email with specific subject

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

On Outlook 365, so no rules + script allowed as I'm not full admin on the machine.

I need to check when mail arrives,
if it has some specific words in the subject
then save the attachment in a specific folder (it would be better with the name of the mail subject + datestamp) and then put the mail in the bin.

I tried the next code.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  
  Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
'--------------------- ok till here -----------
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Set objAttachments = Msg.Attachments

If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    If InStr(Msg.Subject, "Magic Red Carpet") Then
        
     objAttachments.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\xx12345\Desktop\vba\" & objAttachments.Msg.Subject&date
    End If
End If


ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "dho!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`. You may find it better to not use error handling. If you cannot figure out what the error message means, edit the question to include the error and the line.

Comment: I already tried without error handling but no message/error is presented while no file is being saved

Comment: Where is `Msg` from?

Comment: sry can't understand the question about  'Msg'

Comment: There is no `Msg` to be used in `Msg.Attachments`. There should be an error.

Comment: i tried to modify this original code that worked
[link] https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/

by implementing the if statement

and it seems to me that it should be used by objAttachments = Msg.Attachments
 and the "instr(Msg.Subject"

surely i'm wrong

Comment: The source code uses `Item` since `Msg` does not exist, which is why you should see an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `item` object passed as a parameter to the `ItemAdd` event of the Items class in the code:

```
Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Set objAttachments = Item.Attachments

If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    If InStr(Item.Subject, "Magic Red Carpet") Then
        
     objAttachments.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\xx12345\Desktop\vba\" & objAttachments.Msg.Subject&date
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Note, the `Subject` string may contain symbols not allowed in file names. So, I'd recommend checking for them before calling the `SaveAsFile` method.

Also you may consider handling the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class instead. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.